# Open DivX/XVID videos in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, codec

I started working on a new computer a tried to set everything as it used to be on my old one. Unfortunately switching to 64bit Windows made everything quite difficult.

With the current setup I can only open raw I420 videos converted with memcoder, but I can't open DivX/XVID videos, that I used to on my old PC. I tried ffdshow and K-Lite codec pack. Opening the videos in gspot shows that the codecs are indeed installed.

I've searched for solution all over the Internet, but I couldn't find the solution. I've tried copying the ffmpeg dll into the Python27 folder.

The environment is 64bits Windows 7 Pro

**EDIT:**

I tried saving a video using OpenCV:

I passed -1 to the cv2.VideoWriter function to get the codec selection dialog. The dialog dosn't show the ffdshow codecs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem finally.

Windows7 x64 + Python 2.7 x86 + NumPy x86 + ffdshow x86 + Eclipse x64 is the way to go. Everything is working like a charm. x64 ffdshow is also required for other programs like VirtualDub though.

Answer (score 1):

Problem usually is that FFDshow codec is not installed. 
Download it from http://www.free-codecs.com/ffdshow_download.htm and it will solve a problem