# Why an avi file can not be opened in OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, windows, opencv, avi

I installed OpenCV vers. 2.4.7.2 on a Windows Vista (32-bit) platform, with no reported errors.
Then the following file:

```
C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86\cv2.pyd
```

was moved to:

`C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\`

I have been testing openCV with both images and video (*.avi) files. I have no problems (yet) when
working with images. However, I have found a problem when trying to open avieo files. First, an 
example that works fine:

```
import cv2
path = 'D:/Videos/'
video = 'julius.avi'   # a test avi available from me via email attachment
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(path+video)
result = vid.isOpened()
```

[result returns True for this avi]

However, if I use

```
import cv2 
path = 'D:/Videos/'
video = 'toy_plane_liftoff.avi' # http://cinelerra.org/footage/
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(path+video)
result = vid.isOpened()
```

[result returns False for this avi]

Note, I have tried several other avi files (test avi's downloaded from the web)
and most of them will not open. What can be done to open any "good" avi file? By good avi file I mean one that plays with Windows media player and VLC 2.1.2.

Comment: You should also copy the opencv_ffmpeg.dll to the Python directory. Or there's an other solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799586/open-divx-xvid-videos-in-opencv-python

Comment: @Faust I have two dll's in C:\opencv\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg, **opencv_ffmpeg.dll** and **opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll** and I moved both of them to C:\python27 --- this did not solve the problem. And I do not believe the link that you gave is applicable to my problem.

Comment: Yes @b_m --- sorry about that. I also have a screen capture (*.png file) that shows some of the properties of the avi file. Unfortunately, I do not know how to attach/display this *.png. in a comment.

Comment: Here is some information on the avi that works ok (julius.avi) and the one that does not open (toy_plane_liftoff.avi). For **julius.avi**: Codec: Microsoft Video 1 (CRAM), Resolution: 320x249, Frame rate: 15, Decoded format: 15 bits RGB. For **toy_plane_liftoff.avi**: Codec: Motion JPEG Video (MUPG), Resolution: 640x480, Frame rate: 25, Decoded format: Planar 4:2:2 YUV full scale.

Comment: Did you solve this? Did you try renaming opencv_ffmpeg.dll to  opencv_ffmpeg249.dll